# Extending the session by clicking a button by end user. (using servlets and JSPs)

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have got into scenario where the session is getting expired before the user completely fills a form and submits the form. I want to extend the session by five minutes on user request by clicking a button that is enables two minutes before the session is getting expired. I want this to happen with out loss of any data entered by user till that particular time. For this get accomplished i need to keep track of the time left in the session. I have got the remainig time in the following way
"remainingTimeInMilliseconds = session.getMaxInactiveInterval() (
System.currentTimeMillis - session.getLastAccessedTime() )" . Now when remainingTimeInMilliseconds is less than two minutes( in millis) I want to enable a button to the user to extend the time for five more minutes if required. But I am unable to get how to trigger an event and when the time left is less than two minutes and how to enable the button to user at that particular point of time with out any data loss. Kindly help me in accomplish the task. Thanks in advance for the info and help. Note: I dont want to increase the session time out in web.xml as that is not my requirement and that is the only form that requires increment in the session time and all other forms can be filled in the given session time itself

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return of statement below

```
httpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval() - ((System.currentTimeMillis() - httpSession.getLastAccessedTime())
```

to a variable and simply use an "if statement" in which you either create a java bean to store your variable or you just send this information via a request to your jsp page and write a javascript code in your jsp file which will get this information via java bean or request and if it returns lets say is 2"2 minutes" then sim ply display your button which also carry an increment in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to increase the session timeout in your server or application configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On JSP page where user is going to fill the form use JavaScript/jQuery.

You can use [jquery setTimeout() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

**1000 ms = 1 second**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function(){
  //enable button ......
    ......... 
  },1000);
</script>
```

The function `setTimeout()` is *only executed once.* If you need to repeat execution, use the [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method.

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>   The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){
   //call ajax function and check time interval is less than 2 mins
  },1000);
```